# MongoDB - Error "Too many results for query, truncating output" with $geoNear

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm running a [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) query on my **sharded** cluster (6 nodes with 3 replica sets each of 2 shardsvr and 1 arbiter).
I expect the query to return 1.1m documents. I am recieving only ~130.xxx documents. I am using the Java driver to issue the query and process the data (for now, I'm just counting the documents that get returned). I am using MongoDB 3.2.9 and the latest java driver.

The mongod log shows the following error which is caused by the output document getting larger than 16MB:

```
2016-10-10T12:00:22.933+0200 W COMMAND  [conn22] Too many geoNear results for query { location: { $nearSphere: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10.xxxx, 52.xxxxx] }, $maxDistance: 3900.0 } }, truncating output.
2016-10-10T12:00:22.951+0200 I COMMAND  [conn22] command mydb.data command: geoNear { geoNear: "data", near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10.xxxx, 52.xxxxx ] }, 
    num: 50000000, maxDistance: 3900.0, query: {}, spherical: true, distanceMultiplier: 1.0, includeLocs: true } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:890 reslen:16777310 
    locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1784 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 892 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 892 } } } protocol:op_query 589ms

2016-10-10T12:00:23.183+0200 I COMMAND  [conn22] getmore mydb.data query: { aggregate: "data", pipeline: [ { $geoNear: { near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10.xxxx, 52.xxxxx ] }, 
    distanceField: "dist.calculated", limit: 50000000, maxDistance: 3900.0, query: {}, spherical: true, distanceMultiplier: 1.0, includeLocs: "dist.location" } }, { $project: { _id: false, 
    dist: { calculated: true } } } ], fromRouter: true, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } } cursorid:170255616227 ntoreturn:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:43558 
    reslen:1568108 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1786 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 893 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 893 } } } 820ms
```

The Query:

```
db.data.aggregate([
   {
      $geoNear:{
         near:{
            type:"Point",
            coordinates:[
               10.xxxx,
               52.xxxxx
            ]
         },
         distanceField:"dist.calculated",
         maxDistance:3900,
         num:50000000,
         includeLocs:"dist.location",
         spherical:true
      }
   }
])
```

Note that I issued the query with and without the parameter `num`, both fail with the error shown above.

I expected the query to return chunks of the database once the document size limit (16 MB) gets exceeded. 
What am I missing? How can I retrieve all the data?

Edit:
The query also fails with the same error in the mongod logs when I add a group stage:

```
db.data.aggregate([
   {
      $geoNear:{
         near:{
            type:"Point",
            coordinates:[
               10.xxxx,
               52.xxxxxx
            ]
         },
         distanceField:"dist.calculated",
         maxDistance:3900,
         includeLocs:"dist.location",
         num:2000000,
         spherical:true
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$root_document"
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB Staff member Lungang Fang has answered to my enquiry on the MongoDB user group in the meantime. Below is his answer:

> Currently, the “geoNear” aggregation stage is limited to return
>   results that are within the 16MB BSON size limit. This is related to
>   an issue with earlier version of MongoDB (which is described in
>   https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13486). Your query hit this
>   issue because “geoNear” returns a single document (contains an array
>   of result documents) and the “allowDiskUse” aggregation pipeline
>   option unfortunately does not help in this case.
>
> There are two options that could be considered:
>
> If you don’t need all the results, you could limit the “geoNear”
>   aggregation result size using num, limit, or maxDistance options If
>   you require all of the results, you can use the find() operator which
>   is not limited to the BSON maximum size since it returns a cursor.
>   Below is a test I done on MongoDB 3.2.10 For your information.
>
> Create “2dsphere” for designated collection:
>        `db.coll.createIndex({location: '2dsphere'})`
>    Create and insert several big documents:
>   `var padding = '';
>        for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
>            for (var i = 1024*128; i > 0; --i) {
>                var padding = padding + '12345678';
>            }
>        }`
>
> ```
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.861, 40.73]}, padding:padding})
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.862, 40.73]}, padding:padding})
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.863, 40.73]}, padding:padding})
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.864, 40.73]}, padding:padding})
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.865, 40.73]}, padding:padding})
>  db.coll.insert({location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.866, 40.73]}, padding:padding}) Query using “geoNear” and server log shows “Too many geoNear results …, truncating output”
>  db.coll.aggregate(
>      [
>          {
>              $geoNear:{
>                  near:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.86, 40.73]},
>                  distanceField:"dist.calculated",
>                  maxDistance:150000000,
>                  spherical:true
>              }
>          },
>          {$project: {location:1}}
>      ]
>  ) Query using “find” and all expected documents are returned
>  // This and following "var" are necessary to avoid the screen being flushed by padding string.
>  var cursor = db.coll.find (
>      {
>          location: {
>              $near: {
>                  $geometry:{type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.86, 40.73]},
>                  maxDistance:150000,
>              }
>          }
>      }
>  )
>
>  // It is necessary to iterate through the cursor. Otherwise, the query is not actually executed.
>  var x = cursor.next()
>  x._id
>  var x = cursor.next()
>  x._id
>  ...
> ```
>
> Regards, Lungang